# Сan't send a document with a preliminary f.read()

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a problem with unloading a file into a message.

I used the following code:

```
with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    bot.send_document(chat_id, f)
```

But there are cases when the file is empty.
In this case `py-telegram-bot-api` raises a `telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException` (as in any other case with a failed request to the Telegram Bot API!)

```
line 189, in _check_result    
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: 
        A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 
        Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty
```

Since I can't catch the "empty file" error specifically, I decided to pre-check the file:

```
with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
    if not text:
       bot.send_message(chat_id, "File is empty")
       return
    bot.send_document(chat_id, f)
```

But now I am constantly told that the file is empty, even if it is not.

Experimentally I found out that this happens exactly after `f.read()`

What does `f.read()` do, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Calling `.read()` leaves the current file position at the end of the file.  When `send_document()` tries to read the file itself, it finds nothing further to read.  One solution would be to call `.seek(0)` on the file, to rewind it to the beginning.

Comment: Why don't you just do `bot.send_message(chat_id, text)` since you already read it?

Comment: @Barmar, because I need to send a file, not text from a file.